scrolling master window containing Labels and a Canvas in the same area
I try to implement a master window with a scrollbar. This window contains Labels and a Canvas (connected with 'create_line') in the same area.
I need to use label.place instructions (not a grid) because I want to choose the exact location where I put my labels.
I want all the labels and lines to be scrolled at the same time on this window.
Here is what I achieved to do: only lines are scrolling, not the labels.
import tkinter as tk

# Create master window
fenetre = tk.Tk()
fenetre.title("Fenêtre principale avec Canvas et Scrollbar")

# Create canvas
canevas = tk.Canvas(fenetre, width=800, height=600, bg="white")
canevas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH)
canevas.config(scrollregion =(0, 0, 5, 2000))

# Add scrollbar associated to Canvas
scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(fenetre, command=canevas.yview)
scrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
canevas.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

# Draw a line on Canvas
canevas.create_line(50, 50, 200, 150, fill="blue")

# Créez Label 
etiquette = tk.Label(fenetre, text="Ceci est une étiquette")
etiquette.place(x=10, y=30)

# main loop
fenetre.mainloop()


You need to add your Labels to the Canvas via .create_window().  Using .place() or other geometry managers does not allow the scrollbar to control them.

Why don't you use .create_text() instead of label?

Add this before mainloop().
canevas.create_window(0, 0, window=etiquette, anchor='nw')
canevas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)


Sorry to post this here, but there is no MP on SO. I just see you editing lot of post, but it seems you don't really check for the content by itself. You missed some several things (obvisou close reason, so not useful to edit), or just put real phrase at code. I see you have lot of edit, I suggest you to make less edit but more efficients one (note: this answer should include explaination but whatever)

Use .create_text() instead of label to add text into canvas:
import tkinter as tk

# Create master window
fenetre = tk.Tk()
fenetre.title("Fenêtre principale avec Canvas et Scrollbar")

# Create canvas
canevas = tk.Canvas(fenetre, width=800, height=600, bg="white")
canevas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH)
canevas.config(scrollregion =(0, 0, 5, 2000))

# Add scrollbar associated to Canvas
scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(fenetre, command=canevas.yview)
scrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
canevas.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

# Draw a line on Canvas
canevas.create_line(50, 50, 200, 150, fill="blue")
# Create text
canevas.create_text(10, 30, text="Ceci est une étiquette", anchor='nw')

# main loop
fenetre.mainloop()


OP wanted to use the label widget and not .create_text(). As mentioned by @jasonharper

Thank you all, with 'create_window', it works perfectly.
